# Azure load test task fails with invalid secret url

Tags: azure, azure-devops, jmeter, azure-keyvault

I'm trying azure load test config yaml as listed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/reference-test-config-yaml.

My yaml looks like below. Changed the values to obscure actual values.

```
version: v0.1
testName: myloadtest
testPlan: myloadtest_openedit.jmx
description: Load test my web api
engineInstances: 1
configurationFiles:
  - 'loadtestconfig.csv'
failureCriteria:
  - avg(response_time_ms) > 3000
  - percentage(error) > 50

secrets:
  - name: secret_one
    value: https://<resource>.vault.azure.net/secrets/<secret1-id>
  - name: secret_two
    value: https://<resource>.vault.azure.net/secrets/<secret2-id>
keyVaultReferenceIdentity: /subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/<identity-name>
```

The load test task fails with error (invalid secret url) attached

[Azure load test task failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v6sZ.png)

Comment: I'm concerned that the error message isn't helpful.  I recommend that you enable logging on the key vault and check to see if the request makes it to the key vault.  If so, check the HTTP status code.  If not, then something must be blocking the connection between the two endpoints.

Comment: Did you grant read access for Azure Load Testing resource to your Azure Key Vault? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/how-to-use-a-managed-identity?tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-to-your-azure-key-vault